# Parsing a string output into python data structures

Tags: python, string, quotes, modularity

I have this functions that returns a string variable:

```
partition_ = partition(population)
```

this output :
`"[{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}]"`

and i want to assign this output to this function:

```
B = nx_comm.modularity(F1, [{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}])
```

but since it's a string, the modularity function doesn't accept it because of the quotes i guess.
can anyone please help tell me how can i solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't actually output a string, it just is converted to a string when printed out on the console. Try something like `B = nx_comm.modularity(F1, partition_)`? It's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: @SumnerEvans yeah i already did that but it doesn't accept the variable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a function to parse the output string into the format you want. This is a simple parser i made that should create the output you need. Let me know if it works.

```
partition_ = "[{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}]"


def custom_parser(string):

    list_of_sets = []

    temp = []

    begin_set = False

    for char in string:

        if begin_set:

            if char == '}':

                begin_set = False

                temp2 = set(temp)

                list_of_sets.append(temp2)

                temp = []

            elif char not in ['\'', ',', ' ']:

                temp.append(char)

        if char == '{':

            begin_set = True

    return list_of_sets


new_partition_ = custom_parser(partition_)
```

Comment: the int type is not working, i have this error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: Do you know what type of data and in what form `nx_comm.modularity()` requires?

Comment: the print output is : <class 'str'>   , nx_comm.modularity() requires something like [ { ' ' , ' ' , ' '}, { ' ' , ' ' } , { ' ' } ]

Comment: Oh okay I think i figured this out. Reading your first comment response you say it gets stuck on `'['` or the first square bracket. From that I can gather that the entire output is a string like this `"[{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}]"` whereas you wrote it is a list of sets like this `[{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}]` I think I understand the issue now. Give me a minute and Ill figure something out for you

Comment: @ayloul I have updated my answer. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thank you so much, i've been struggling with this for days.

Comment: You're welcome! Just for further clarity, string values like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` weren't the problem. They are expected to be strings by the function. The problem was that the `list` data structure `[...]` and the `set` data structures `{...}` were also  string values and not the actual characters used by the python interpreter. Writing a `list` like this `"[1, 2, 3]"` does not create a `list` object it creates a `string` object. Same with a `set`.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
B = nx_comm.modularity(F1, [int(j)  for i in partition_ for j in i ])
```

Comment: no i don't want to put this [{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}] manually because i have 10 others.

Comment: so in fact, when i type this : B = nx_comm.modularity(F1, [{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}]) it works perfectly,    but when i type B = nx_comm.modularity(F1, partition_) it says NotAPartition error.  and i think it's because the output of partition_ is of type str

Comment: Writing an integer wrapped in quotes casts it to a string though so writing `'3'` is the same as putting `str(3)`

Comment: change  [ int(j)  for i in [{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}] for j in i ] to [str(j)  for i in [{'3', '4'}, {'1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}] for j in i ] then check fine or not?